# Function accessing data from enclosing environment

Tags: r

I am working with the segmented package and have encountered a problem when calling `davies.test()` from within a function.

Consider the following situation:

```
library(segmented)

data = data.frame(x = 1:21, y = c(10:1, 0:10))
fit = lm(y ~ x, data = data)
fit.seg = segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~ x)
davies.test(fit.seg, seg.Z = ~ x, alternative = "greater")
```

That works perfectly and indicates that the segmented regression has two statistically different slopes.

Now if I package all of that up into a function like this:

```
testit <- function() {
  data = data.frame(x = 1:21, y = c(10:1, 0:10))
  fit = lm(y ~ x, data)
  fit.seg = segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~ x)
  davies.test(fit.seg, seg.Z = ~ x, alternative = "greater")$p.value
}
testit()
```

Then it works fine...

But if I delete `fit` from the global environment then it fails.

```
> rm(fit)
> testit()
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'fit' not found
```

The problem seems to be with the way that `davies.test` is trying to access the data encapsulated in `fit`: it doesn't seem to look for `fit` in the enclosing scope (which in this case is the `testit` function), but skips directly to the global scope.

I'm sure that the problem relates to some subtlety with R's scoping rules. If I can find a quick fix that would prevent me from troubling the package author with this edge case, that would be great.

Thanks,
Andrew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try inserting the line marked `##` below.  There is still a difference that this does not account for as shown by the warning that appears when the modified `testit` is run but the output pvalue is the same so it may be sufficient for your needs.  This is, of course, a bug in the package and best would really be to ask the maintainer of the package if they would fix it.

```
library(segmented)
testit <- function() {
  data = data.frame(x = 1:21, y = c(10:1, 0:10))
  fit = lm(y ~ x, data)
  fit.seg = segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~ x)
  environment(davies.test) <- environment() ##
  davies.test(fit.seg, seg.Z = ~ x, alternative = "greater")$p.value
}
testit()
```

giving:

```
[1] 0.01858149
Warning message:
In summary.lm(object) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

Comment: Thanks. That warning is just due to the way that the test data are constructed. Not a related issue.

Answer (score 3):

No need to make it a global variable.  The problem is actually in `segmented`, not `davies.test`.  It's not finding `fit`.

You can use `dynGet` to locate `fit` in any environment, including the calling function's environment:

```
testit <- function() {
  data = data.frame(x = 1:21, y = c(10:1, 0:10))
  fit = lm(y ~ x, data)
  fit.seg = segmented(dynGet("fit"), seg.Z = ~ x)
  davies.test(fit.seg, seg.Z = ~ x, alternative = "greater")$p.value
}
testit()
```

That should work as you intend.

If you have multiple variables named `fit` in different environments, then use `get` (see `?get`) to specify which environment you want to get it from.  `dynGet` is the "look everywhere; return first" lazy version.

Comment: The problem is evaluation inside `davis.test`. See `traceback` output.

Comment: The specific environment of the calling function can be accessed with: `segmented(get("fit", sys.frame(1)), seg.Z = ~ x)`

That avoids the possible namespace clash elsewhere when using `dynGet()`.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the author of `segmented` and he promptly responded. Another solution he proposed to the original issue would be

```
testit <- function() {
  data = data.frame(x = 1:21, y = c(10:1, 0:10))
  fit = lm(y ~ x, data)
  fit.seg = segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~ x)
  fit.seg$call$obj<-fit
  davies.test(fit.seg, seg.Z = ~ x, alternative = "greater")$p.value
}
```

However, he also pointed out that the `lm` object should actually be passed directly to `davies.test()` as follows:

```
testit <- function() {
  data = data.frame(x = 1:21, y = c(10:1, 0:10))
  fit = lm(y ~ x, data)
  davies.test(fit, seg.Z = ~ x, alternative = "greater")$p.value
}
```

For clarification though, it should be noted that these two bits of code do different things: the second fragment actually fulfills my original purpose (checking for a statistically significant break in the fit), while the first fragment checks to see whether there is a *second* break.